# Woocommerce admin product categories table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Can anyone tell me if there is a hook I can use to change the way product categories are displayed in the woo commerce admin products > categories section.

I want to customize the way categories are filtered depending on which account created them. Multiple users can create categories and I am storing a user id in  wp_termmeta so I can relate the product category to the user that created it.

Here is an image of the area I want to be able to hook into and customize the data that is being displayed.

Comment: Not sure why the image link didn't work. Here it is

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/kao6le/9

Comment: I'm also searching for a way to edit this page and surprisingly there's little (if any) information on how to do that without overwriting the core... So far the only way I could think of is to add a JS file to the back-end and use AJAX for modifications, but that sounds almost as terribly wrong as editing Woocommerce's core... If you've found a better solution, please share it here.

Comment: Check out this answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26573682/3196951 It shows how you can add custom fields and contents to the categories' table. Maybe you would also find it useful.